# How to calculate field data from 2x LEFT JOIN's

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to calculate the fuel consumption of our plant.
My query is a LEFT JOIN, the first 'qry1' calculates the total hours the plant have run for the current month, 'qry2' calculates the total diesel used by each plant.

These work fine on their own, but adding 'qry3', which is supposed to devide the answer from 'qry2' with 'qry1' and give the average diesel consumption, but I do not know how to use the output from each of these LEFT JOIN's and use result to make the (supposed to be very easy) calculation:

```
SELECT 
 `plant`.`plant_id`,
 `qry1`.`total_hrs`, 
 `qry2`.`total_d`, 
 `qry3`.`consumption`

FROM `plant` 

  LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT (MAX(`plant_hrs_stop`)- MIN(`plant_hrs_start`) ) AS total_hrs, `plant_id` 
   FROM`plant_hrs`  
   WHERE MONTH(`plant_hrs_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )  
   GROUP BY`plant_id` 
  ) AS `qry1` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry1`.`plant_id` 

  LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT (SUM(`diesel_qty`) ) AS total_d, `diesel_vehicle_no` AS `plant_id` 
   FROM`diesel`  
   WHERE MONTH(`diesel_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )  
   GROUP BY `diesel_vehicle_no` 
  ) AS `qry2` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry2`.`plant_id` 

  LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT (`qry2`.`total_d` / `qry1`.`total_hrs`) AS consumption,    
   FROM `qry1`, `qry2`  
   GROUP BY `plant_id` 
  ) AS `qry3` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry3`.`plant_id`

ORDER BY `plant`.`plant_id`
```

I keep on getting an errors, I have tried a few searches but keep on coming up empty...

Comment: ... and what do these errors say?

Comment: your are using `group by` without using any aggregate functions in qry3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another join to do the final calculation, you can just do:

```
select `plant`.`plant_id`,
    `qry1`.`total_hrs`,
    `qry2`.`total_d`,
    (`qry2`.`total_d` / `qry1`.`total_hrs`) as consumption
from `plant`
left join (
    select (MAX(`plant_hrs_stop`) - MIN(`plant_hrs_start`)) as total_hrs,
        `plant_id` 
    FROM`plant_hrs`
    where MONTH(`plant_hrs_date`) = MONTH(current_date)
    group by `plant_id`
    ) as `qry1` on `plant`.`plant_id` = `qry1`.`plant_id`
left join (
    select (SUM(`diesel_qty`)) as total_d,
        `diesel_vehicle_no` as `plant_id`
    from `diesel`
    where MONTH(`diesel_date`) = MONTH(current_date)
    group by `diesel_vehicle_no`
    ) as `qry2` on `plant`.`plant_id` = `qry2`.`plant_id`
order by `plant`.`plant_id`
```

Note that just using MONTH in the where clause means you will get data from more than one year. If this is not what is intended, use YEAR() as well.

Comment: Jee-Wizz, that was a quick answer and it works thank you so much. One last question: How do I limit the answer to a 2 decimal answer?

Comment: You can use the [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function for that, e.g., `FORMAT(MyColumn, 2)`.

Comment: thanx I will change my query to include the year as well, did not think that one through...

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvote. (I assume it was by HLGEM, who -- despite his high rep -- seems to be either clueless or a troll.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the last join. 
**And make sure `qry1.total_hrs <> 0`** :

```
SELECT 
 `plant`.`plant_id`,
 `qry1`.`total_hrs`, 
 `qry2`.`total_d`, 
 `qry3`.`consumption`,
  if(COALESCE(`qry1`.`total_hrs`,0)<>0,'qry2`.`total_d` / `qry1`.`total_hrs`,NULL) AS consumption

FROM `plant` 

  LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT (MAX(`plant_hrs_stop`)- MIN(`plant_hrs_start`) ) AS total_hrs, `plant_id` 
   FROM`plant_hrs`  
   WHERE MONTH(`plant_hrs_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )  
   GROUP BY`plant_id` 
  ) AS `qry1` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry1`.`plant_id` 

  LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT (SUM(`diesel_qty`) ) AS total_d, `diesel_vehicle_no` AS `plant_id` 
   FROM`diesel`  
   WHERE MONTH(`diesel_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )  
   GROUP BY `diesel_vehicle_no` 
  ) AS `qry2` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry2`.`plant_id` 

ORDER BY `plant`.`plant_id`
```

Comment: Excellent, you are the only person answered who caught that division must never be allowed to have a 0 in the bottom of the equation. A division shoudl not ever be writen without a coalesce. Now the OP needs to determine what value should show if either value inteh division is null, in some cases, they will want to show 0 value instead of null and in some cases they will want to show (as you have done) null. But that is a requirements question only teh OP can get an answer to.

Comment: @HLGEM: I doubt it's possible for `total_hrs` to be `0`. (*That* is a requirements question that only the OP can answer.) And your statement that "A division shoudl not ever be writen without a coalesce" makes no sense, firstly because `coalesce` checks for `null` rather than for `0`, and secondly because usually, when someone is writing a division, it's because they know the divisor can never be zero.

Comment: @ruakh, you can never make that assumption and espcially not here where the left jon guarantees taht there wil be nulls. The way he has written it correctly checks and it is irresponsible to not do these checks in a division. I have seen many a division query blow up because the dev made unjustified assumptions about whether the numbers could come out to 0 or null.

Comment: @HLGEM: Sorry, but I think you're confused. Division by `NULL` is `NULL`; it doesn't cause any sort of "blowing up". (For that matter -- the question is tagged `mysql`, and in MySQL, division by `0` is also `NULL`, and doesn't cause any sort of "blowing up". But it's at least *understandable* that you might want to avoid dividing by `0`. What's *not* understandable is taking extra steps to avoid dividing by `NULL`.)

Comment: Becasue most of teh time, the users don't want to see null as the value returned as they don't know what null means.